# ARC related error

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

[image]I have a project in working/running condition for WebService calling and in which 
Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting is set "Yes".

I want to use this code to my another existing code which also has:
Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting is set "Yes" but after adding all the necessary files and frameworks, it is throwing error for 'ARC forbids explicit message'.

please help as I am stucked !!

Comment: Show where the message happens.

Comment: r u sure that working project has arc enabled?

Comment: yes i have checked for that so i am sure about that

Comment: Post the code, where the error is happening

Comment: in your error project have you used release, retain or autorelease?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877025/arc-forbids-explicit-message-send-of-retain-issue check this link

Comment: I know i am using retain,release which is wrong in case of ARC 'Yes' but this same code is in working condition as seperate code

Comment: its really strange that when i am using Webservice Call project as diffrnt projct then it was working with ARC set as 'Yes' also but on adding to existing it is showing error for release,retain etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Flag **"-fno-objc-arc"** under *project setting > Build phases>compile Sources* and add this Flag against Non ARC Files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *-fno-objc-arc* compiler flag:

double click on empty space in "Compiler flags" column for non-arc .m file row

[image]

Comment: its really strange that when i am using Webservice Call project as diffrnt projct then it was working with ARC set as 'Yes' also but on adding to existing it is showing error for release,retain etc.